# Send Big query table rows to Kafka avro message using apache beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, avro, apache-beam-kafkaio

I need to publish the Big query table rows to Kafka in Avro format.

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows =
        pipeline
            .apply(
                "Read from BigQuery query",
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(String.format("%s:%s.%s", project, dataset, table))
    
//How to convert rows to avro format?

rows.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, ???>write()
                .withBootstrapServers("kafka:29092")
                .withTopic("test")
                .withValueSerializer(KafkaAvorSerializer.class)
        );
```

How to convert TableRow to Avro format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MapElements`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/elementwise/mapelements/)

```
rows.apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<Tabelrows, GenericRecord>() {
  @Override
  public GenericRecord apply(Tabelrows input) {
    log.info("Parsing {} to Avro", input);
    return null; // TODO: Replace with Avro object
  }
});
```

If `Tabelrows` is a collection-type that you want to convert to many records, you can use `FlatMapElements` instead.

As for writing to Kafka, I [wrote a simple example](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/beam-sandbox/blob/main/src/main/java/cricket/jmoore/beam/BeamKafkaAvroExample.java#L160)

Comment: I am looking on how can we convert the tablerows to avro generic record?

Comment: Well, you mistyped Tabelrow, or haven't shown that class definition so I cannot answer that. Read the Javadoc for TableRows object?... Call getters. Create new a GenericRecord and call setters. Return it. That's not unique to Bigquery

Comment: TableRow is Big query table row format https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html. ... I am not sure how can I convert that table row to the generic record of Avro?

Comment: Your question shows `Tablerows` (with an s). I don't know what that is. But the linked class implements Map, so like I said, call `input.get("column")`...then read the Javadoc for GenericRecord, and you'll see it has set methods. I trust you're capable of figuring it out